# skip invalid documents and upload valid ones from single file using INSERT aql with arangodb

Tags: validation, insert, arangodb, aql, nosql

I am using the following aql query for uploading documents from a file into the database `"FOR document in @file INSERT document INTO @@collection LET newDoc = NEW RETURN newDoc"`.
I have created a unique hash index for all attributes in the collection so when attempting to upload a duplicated document I get an error (which I wanted) but then none of the documents from the file is uploaded to the database. 
I would like to know if is there a way to upload only the valid documents and skip the wrong ones (in my case duplicated documents) by using aql query.

UPDATE:

I am using python and I can upload documents one by one as:

```
for document in file:
    doc = collection.createDocument() #function from pyArango
    try:
        for key, value in document.iteritems():
            doc[key] =  value
            doc.save()
    except:
        print "wrong document"
```

I was wondering if I can do it using aql query and not "manually" upload one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `ignoreErrors: true` in the query [OPTIONS statement](https://docs.arangodb.com/AqlExamples/DataModificationQueries.html#replacing-documents) like this:

```
FOR document in @file 
  INSERT document INTO @@collection OPTIONS {ignoreErrors: true}
  RETURN NEW
```

It will then ignore the documents with collisions and will only return those documents that were actually created.

If you try to only return the `_key` field, you will gett a `null` for each failed document:

```
FOR document in @file 
  INSERT document INTO @@collection OPTIONS {ignoreErrors: true}
  RETURN NEW._key
```

The Result will look like this, first being a duplicate, the second fresh generated `_key` with value `23225`:

```
[ 
  null, 
  "23225" 
]
```